# How turn off transparency in UIStatusBarStyle?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Transparency in the status bar does not turn off, I tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

It only changes text color(

How turn off transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Just add subview at the top of your View.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar will always be transparent unless you use either:

A subview at the top of your VC's behind the bar.

A navigation controller and navigation bar.

Add a background colour to the UIWindow in the status bars view.